# Producing multiple PDF plots of mapsheets specified by shapefile key from ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, pdf, data-driven-pages, map-book

I'm looking for a product that will produce multiple pdf plots of mapsheets specified by a shapefile key (say, 11 x 17) from ArcGIS 9.3 using a single .mxd template, include and orient a common keymap, etc.  The DS Mapbook extension from the ESRI developer samples is one of these, but it's an old VB6 product and am wondering if there's anything else similar, newer and maybe commercially available.

Comment: Does anyone know if DS Mapbook will be extended to ArcGIS 10? thanks,
Jesse

Comment: @Jesse It's hard to know but it seems like they are putting all their eggs into Data Driven Pages.  MPS Atlas isn't even available as an extension at 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use MapLogic Layout Manager, and have for about four or five years.  We're able to create some nice map books with this software, and it's much more advanced than the DS Mapbook extension.  Since we started using their software we're constantly asked to create new map books for departments.  You can find them at [MapLogic](http://www.maplogic.com/).

Comment: I've got it on a trial version; in a commercial environment this is the way to go especially with support, awareness of ESRI version upgrades and NO VB6 COMPILER NEEDED! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Mapbook has been extended as a [Google code project](http://sites.google.com/site/arcmapbook/). The last update was (I believe) in Feb 09. @matt wilkie heads up the project, so he should be able to comment further.

Comment: Arcmapbook, what I call my bundling of DS Mapbook, is not that different from the developer sample. It's primary difference is having everything (documentation, user to user help, bug reporting) in one place. There have been some minor bug fixes and improvements to the install/uninstall process. I've also collected together some of the more noteworthy development extensions but a person needs a VB6 to take advantage. VB6 is hard to acquire, accounting for the glacial pace of improvement. I expect Arc10's data driven pages to eventually supercede everything, though it doesn't do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that anyone coming across this question, who is using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 or later, should review [What are Data Driven Pages?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003m000000):

> Data Driven Pages allow you to quickly and easily create a series of
>   layout pages from a single map document. A feature layer, or index
>   layer, divides the map into sections based on each index feature in
>   the layer and generates one page per index feature.
>
> In order to use Data Driven Pages to build a map book you need to use
>   arcpy.mapping. Arcpy.mapping is a Python scripting module that is part
>   of the ArcPy site package. This module provides functions to automate
>   exporting and printing. Arcpy.mapping can be used to automate map
>   production; it extends the capabilities of Data Driven Pages and is
>   required to build complete map books because it includes functions to
>   export to, create, and manage PDF documents.

Personally, I think you can create a very simple map book without using arcpy.mapping, but for anything harder I would agree with the above.