# How to Automate ArcGIS map production?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, pdf, data-driven-pages

I am currently working with high volume ArcGIS (9.3.1 & 10) production of PDF files, part of the companies requirement is that a database (Access 2003) needs filling out with each map, this needs an automated (sequential) map number, the mxd location and the user (3 digit reference). This also needs to be filled on the map template in the specified fields of the map.

I have seen some python script for exporting the layers of a map to a table, is there a way that I can automate my process so that I can fill the "username" field on the map and then have ArcGIS populate the "figure number" field with the next sequential number and then populate a table which I can link to the DB which my company uses?

This would make my life a lot easier and I can see how it is possible though my python is letting me down.

Comment: This is nearly duplicate question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/arcgis-9-3-mapbook?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to use what ESRI call "automating map workflows" - its a new feature in ArcGIS 10 - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp0000001t000000.htm

You may also want to have a look at their [Map Books](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000002s000000.htm) page.